# VBA to replace index match formula

Tags: vba, excel

i am new to VBA and trying to find my way through the following scenario:

sheet1 with columns A (item) B (Description) C (Price) (this is my search sheet)

sheet2 with the same exact columns (this is my database sheet)

what i want to do is: When i enter an item code in sheet1 column a, match the unique value from sheet2 and copy paste the values from columns B and C to sheet1 for this item.

i want this to happen only for the active cell in sheet1, is that possible?

i hope i was clear enough
kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following code to the `Sheet1 module`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error Resume Next
    'if changed entire range ITEMS1'
    If Target.Name.Name = "ITEMS1" Then
        Dim tarRange As Range
        Set tarRange = Application.Intersect(Range("ITEMS1"), Target)
        If Not tarRange Is Nothing Then
            Dim sh2 As Worksheet
            Dim res As Range
            Dim tarRow As Range

            'change "Sheet2" to the sheet name that is true for you'
            Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

            For Each tarRow In tarRange.Cells

                Set res = sh2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=tarRow.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)

                If res Is Nothing Then
                    tarRow.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = "not found"
                    'MsgBox "There is no matching value on Sheet2"
                Else
                    'if we found value on sheet2, than copy range B,C'
                    tarRow.Resize(1, 3).Value = res.Resize(1, 3).Value
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Simoco, just a quick question is there any way we can exempt two words from this macro? what i want to do: every time the macro will find the words date or item in the column a:a not to do anything.

Comment: Am I understand you correctly, if we enter in column `A` words "date" or "item", then macro should do nothing?

Comment: exactly. when we enter date or item it shouldn't do nothing

Comment: Change line `If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then` to `If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing And Target<>"item" And Target<>"date" Then`

Comment: I hope this is the last time i bother you guys, but is there any chance that this code can be converted to do the following:

Comment: every time we run a macro a whole range (we have named ranges for example A2:A100 = ITEMS1) will be updated?

Comment: You want to run a macro only if changed entire range A2:A100 in the same time?

Comment: what happens is that we have ranges for different depts so a2:a100 is one dept, instead of manually updating all the cells one by one i don't know if there is a way to update the whole range at once.

Comment: 1) add `On error resume next` in the beggining of the macro. 2) change `If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then` to `If Target.Name.Name="ITEMS1" Then` . But note, that it will work only in case when entire range is changed (i.e. when you paste new values in entire range using copy/paste)

Comment: Thank you very much Simoco, but it still changes only on line (the active one ) i tried to copy and paste the cells A2:A100 and i got results only in the first line

Comment: hi Simoco, something is not working with the new code, when i try to insert a line the excel keeps thinking until it crashes, any ideas?

Comment: Updated answer. Try now.

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to use VBA to replace using a formula, but you didn't say why.  VBA is great but I think formulas are the way to go for this particular job.

Format the data in Sheet1 and Sheet2 and Table1 and Table2 respectively, then:

In Table1 column B, type:

```vba
=INDEX(Table2[Description],MATCH([Item],Table2[Item],0),)
```

In Table1 column C, type:

```vba
=INDEX(Table2[Price],MATCH([Item],Table2[Item],0),)
```

Voila